# Oracle Coherence - Trying to start the default server

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I am trying to run DefaultCacheServer in eclipse. I have enabled storage for server. I get the following error:

*2013-08-27 16:51:03.891/0.141 Oracle Coherence 3.6.1.0  (thread=main, member=n/a): Loaded operational overrides from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/coherence/lib/coherence.jar!/tangosol-coherence-override-dev.xml"

2013-08-27 16:51:03.906/0.156 Oracle Coherence 3.6.1.0  (thread=main, member=n/a): Loaded operational overrides from "file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/WSCoherence/Cache/config/tangosol-coherence-override.xml"

2013-08-27 16:51:03.906/0.156 Oracle Coherence 3.6.1.0  (thread=main, member=n/a): Optional configuration override "/cluster-config.xml" is not specified

2013-08-27 16:51:03.906/0.156 Oracle Coherence 3.6.1.0  (thread=main, member=n/a): Optional configuration override "/custom-mbeans.xml" is not specified

Oracle Coherence Version 3.6.1.0 Build 19636

Grid Edition: Development mode
Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
2013-08-27 16:51:04.062/0.312 Oracle Coherence GE 3.6.1.0  (thread=main, member=n/a): Loaded cache configuration from "file:/C:/Program Files/Java/WSCoherence/Cache/config/product-config-coherence-cache-config.xml"

2013-08-27 16:51:04.062/0.312 Oracle Coherence GE 3.6.1.0  (thread=main, member=n/a):

Services
  (
 ***-------DONT SEE ANYTHING ------***
  )

Started DefaultCacheServer...*

Coherence version - 3.6
JDK version-1.6

Classpath - (In Order) - JRE system lib, overridden Config files and coherence.jar.

```
This is my config file


And this is my overriden file.

<cluster-name>ProductConfig</cluster-name> 
   <role-name>PC1</role-name>  
    </member-identity>    
<!--  Enable Single Server mode, as we have only one JVM. -->
      <unicast-listener>
       <address system-property="tangosol.coherence.localhost">127.0.0.1
      </address>
      </unicast-listener>
      <multicast-listener>
      <time-to-live system-property="tangosol.coherence.ttl">0</time-to-live>
      </multicast-listener>   
    </cluster-config>      
    <configurable-cache-factory-config>  
       <init-params>  
          <init-param>  
             <param-type>java.lang.String</param-type> 
             <param-value system-property="tangosol.coherence.cacheconfig">  
               product-config-coherence-cache-config.xml 
    </param-value>  
          </init-param>  
       </init-params>  
   </configurable-cache-factory-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config files are not correct most likely. You must have a config file that specifies what caches will be known in the system. Those start with `<cache-config>` element.
Also, as a good practice, always check that Coherence actually loads your config files and doesn't ignore them. Coherence tends to quietly fail and proceed with default settings.